# Rails conditions, how to work around nils being dropped from arrays?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

For both basic conditions (like find statements) and the more general where clause, users have the ability to look for any of a group of conditions. For example:

```
User.find_by_name(["One", "Two", "Three"])
User.find_by_name_and_age(["One", "Two"],[1,2,3])
```

or

```
User.where(:bonus_id => [1,2,3])
```

Their is a slight inconsistance here, though. If you use

```
User.find_by_bonus_id([nil,1,2])
```

This will return uses with a bonus id of "nil", as could be expected! However, both the "find_by_...*and*..." format and "where" format do NOT work this way.

```
User.where(:bonus_id => [nil,1])
```

Will return ONLY those Users with a bonus_id of 1.

```
User.where(:bonus_id => [nil]
```

will return nothing all!

```
User.where(:bonus_id => nil)
```

however, works fine.

As near as I can tell, the where clause (and find_by_and method) collapse their arrays, removing any values that are non-truthy. This is a pretty significant problem for me.

**Does anyone know a way to include nils in a where clause array (or a workaround), or am I going to have to end up joining multiple queries together in order to obtain the right behaviour?**

> Additional Notes:
>   - Version 3.0.11
>   - Nils are not actually being dropped, but rather under certain circumstances it is comparing IN (NULL) instead of IS NULL in the SQL. I'm leaving the title as is, since even though it is inaccurate, it's how the problem appears at first when encountered.

Comment: rails version? in 3.2.0 `find_all_by_xyz` and `where` work exactly the same (as you expect, `nil` is included)

Comment: 3.0.11. It could be that this wasn't the intended behaviour and it's since been fixed.

Comment: What does `User.where(:bonus_id => [nil,1]).to_sql` say in 3.0.11? I only have a 3.2 handy and that correctly splits the `nil` into a separate `or x is null` chunk in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Ah, good question!  It returns: 
"SELECT users.* FROM users WHERE users.firstname IN (NULL)"

Comment: While without the braces, I get "SELECT users.* FROM users WHERE users.firstname IS NULL"

Comment: Yeah, I guess `nil` maps to IS NULL, which is what you would want, except that it doesn't in Rails versions including, but not necessarily limited to, 3.0.11, and only when you use brackets. Kind of an esoteric issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not able to reproduce your problem on Rails 3.1.0. What version are you using?

Try this:

```
User.where(["bonus_id IN (?) OR bonus_id IS NULL", [1,2]])
```

Will return users where the bonus_id is either 1, 2, or null

Comment: I don't know that I'd consider this a workaround. I'd just consider it the answer. An important thing to understand is that *NULLs are not values* and, therefore, *nothing is equal to NULL*, not even NULL, so checking if something is equal to NULL (which I believe `nil` would map to) doesn't make sense, because it will never be true.

Comment: Jason, except, of course, that checking for nil values DOES work under every other condition beyond this one. Your statement is manifestly untrue. Except the first part - I also suspect this is the answer.

Comment: Good point! Also, it looks like I was wrong about `nil` mapping to = NULL. It maps to IS NULL, which is of course different.

Comment: Hang on, I'm pretty sure everything I said in my first comment is correct except for the part about `nil` mapping to NULL. NULLs are not values and nothing is equal to NULL. (`nil` is a different story.)

Comment: Hah, yeah, sorry, good point, that "nil" mapping bit was the only actual wrong part, and you did say you were unsure. According to the SQL up above, thats exactly the problem, too (and what later versions seem to have fixed)